# Inconsistencies when using UnsafeMutablePointer with String or Character types

Tags: string, swift, pointers, generics, unsafe-pointers

I'm currently trying to implement my own `DynamicArray` data type in Swift. To do so I'm using pointers a bit. As my `root` I'm using an `UnsafeMutablePointer` of a generic type `T`:

```
struct DynamicArray<T> {
    private var root: UnsafeMutablePointer<T> = nil
    private var capacity = 0 {
        didSet {
            //...
        }
    }

    //...

    init(capacity: Int) {
        root = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.alloc(capacity)
        self.capacity = capacity
    }

    init(count: Int, repeatedValue: T) {
        self.init(capacity: count)

        for index in 0..<count {
            (root + index).memory = repeatedValue
        }
        self.count = count
}

    //...
}
```

Now as you can see I've also implemented a `capacity` property which tells me how much memory is currently allocated for `root`. Accordingly one can create an instance of `DynamicArray` using the `init(capacity:)` initializer, which allocates the appropriate amount of memory, and sets the `capacity` property.
But then I also implemented the `init(count:repeatedValue:)` initializer, which first allocates the needed memory using `init(capacity: count)`. It then sets each segment in that part of memory to the `repeatedValue`.

When using the `init(count:repeatedValue:)` initializer with number types like `Int`, `Double`, or `Float` it works perfectly fine. Then using `Character`, or `String` though it crashes. It doesn't crash consistently though, but actually works sometimes, as can be seen [here](http://swiftstub.com/557095600/), by compiling a few times.

```
var a = DynamicArray<Character>(count: 5, repeatedValue: "A")
println(a.description) //prints [A, A, A, A, A]
//crashes most of the time

var b = DynamicArray<Int>(count: 5, repeatedValue: 1)
println(a.description) //prints [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
//works consistently
```

Why is this happening? Does it have to do with `String` and `Character` holding values of different length?

---

#### Update #1:

Now @AirspeedVelocity addressed the problem with `init(count:repeatedValue:)`. The `DynamicArray` contains another initializer though, which at first worked in a similar fashion as `init(count:repeatedValue:)`. I changed it to work, as @AirspeedVelocity described for `init(count:repeatedValue:)` though:

```
init<C: CollectionType where C.Generator.Element == T, C.Index.Distance == Int>(collection: C) {
    let collectionCount = countElements(collection)
    self.init(capacity: collectionCount)
    
    root.initializeFrom(collection)
    count = collectionCount
}
```

I'm using the `initializeFrom(source:)` method as described [here](http://swiftdoc.org/type/UnsafeMutablePointer/). And since `collection` conforms to `CollectionType` it should work fine.
I'm now getting this error though:

```
<stdin>:144:29: error: missing argument for parameter 'count' in call
    root.initializeFrom(collection)
                        ^
```

Is this just a misleading error message again?

Comment: I think that is a @MartinR question

Comment: You shouldn’t ask a new different question by editing your previous question… however, I believe you’re hitting a swift type inference bug in 1.1 that is fixed in the 1.2 beta.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to avoid that in the future. - damnit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, chances are this doesn’t crash with basic inert types like integers but does with strings or arrays because they are more complex and allocate memory for themselves on creation/destruction.

The reason it’s crashing is that `UnsafeMutablePointer` memory needs to be initialized before it’s used (and similarly, needs to de-inited with `destroy` before it is deallocated).

So instead of assigning to the `memory` property, you should use the `initialize` method:

```
for index in 0..<count {
    (root + index).initialize(repeatedValue)
}
```

Since initializing from another collection of values is so common, there’s another version of `initialize` that takes one.  You could use that in conjunction with another helper struct, `Repeat`, that is a collection of the same value repeated multiple times:

```
init(count: Int, repeatedValue: T) {
    self.init(capacity: count)
    root.initializeFrom(Repeat(count: count, repeatedValue: repeatedValue))
    self.count = count
}
```

However, there’s something else you need to be aware of which is that this code is currently inevitably going to leak memory.  The reason being, you will need to  `destroy` the contents and `dealloc` the pointed-to memory at some point before your `DynamicArray` struct is destroyed, otherwise you’ll leak.  Since you can’t have a `deinit` in a struct, only a class, this won’t be possible to do automatically (this is assuming you aren’t expecting users of your array to do this themselves manually before it goes out of scope).

Additionally, if you want to implement value semantics (as with `Array` and `String`) via copy-on-write, you’ll also need a way of detecting if your internal buffer is being referenced multiple times.  Take a look at `ManagedBufferPointer` to see a class that handles this for you.